# Making a theme selector to my chatroom with php js and html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a chatroom a billischill.ddns.net and i want the users to be able to click a button and it change the theme so far this is what my code consist of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var defaultchatbtn = document.getElementById('pickdarkcyan');

   defaultchatbtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
   defaultchatbtn.onclick = function() {
</script>


<html>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_crimson.css" />
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
};
</script>
```

i was using

```
     <?php include('css/style_crimson.css');?>
```

but that just prints the style to the screen any solutions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796107/how-to-make-changeable-themes-using-css-and-javascript Also, I don't know much PHP, but an `include()` just includes the plain text(or code), it doesn't "process" it.

Comment: thank you that helped very much

Comment: @NikHendricks Do you mean that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796107/how-to-make-changeable-themes-using-css-and-javascript solved your problem?

Comment: yes it worked perfectly