# Modify Function to run according to User COOKIE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to modify the following Function to be run first according to User $_COOKIE['theme'] between the 2 themes (light or contrast)

As example i already have this output

```
$_COOKIE['theme'] = contrast
```

How to modify this to work with with my idea ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setTypeLight(type)
{
    $('body').removeClass('black');
    $('.wtop .account li.menu .menu_inner a.typelight').removeClass('light contrast');
    $('.wtop .account li.menu ul li').removeClass('act');

    switch (type)
    {
        case 'light':
            $('.wtop .account li.menu .menu_inner a.typelight').addClass('light');
            $('.wtop .account li.menu ul a.typelight.light').parent('li').addClass('act');
        break;

        case 'contrast':
            $('body').addClass('black');
            $('.wtop .account li.menu .menu_inner a.typelight').addClass('contrast');
            $('.wtop .account li.menu ul a.typelight.contrast').parent('li').addClass('act');
        break;
    }

    ajaxLoad({id: '#', url: '/top/ajax.php?action=param&param=typelight&typelight=' + type + '&sessid=9e6c'}, {nprogress: 'N', type: 'null'});
}

</script>


<li><a href="?theme=light" onClick="setTypeLight('light'); return false;" class="typelight light">light</a></li>

<li><a href="?theme=contrast" onClick="setTypeLight('contrast'); return false;" class="typelight contrast">contrast</a></li>
```

Comment: Why would you tag `Java`!!

Comment: execute it on document ready passing in the cookie value as the argument

Comment: It might be easier to dynamically switch between two css files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796107/how-to-make-changeable-themes-using-css-and-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call get your cookie and call your function on startup

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

$(function(){
    setTypeLight(getCookie('theme'));
});
```

Comment: As the OP is already using jQuery ... `setTypeLight($.cookie('theme'));` ... no need for your cookie cutter :p

Comment: Well yes, but $.cookie is a plugin called jquery-cookie as far as I know? Or is it now part of jQuery core? @JaromandaX

Comment: oh ... sorry, it is a plugin - I'm having a bad jQuery day!!