# Change bootstrap theme runtime

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Actually i need to change theme on client basis using angularjs.
So suppose if my client is "ABC" so need to select theme "bootstrap_abc_theme", if my client is "XYZ" then it will select "bootstrap_xyz_theme" like that. Basically i need to provide different theme to each and every one client.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796160/3621001)?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Yes but i need solution using angularjs and provided solution available in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be:

Use `ng-href` in your `<link>` and modify it's variable in your controller.

[Working DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bbeAx3uFMkpONOsY8Ous?p=preview)